# Display an object with the listView and adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

I'm writing a simple contact list app which allows a user to enter a name and a last name, stores these items in the list and displays them as a list below the editText fields. 
I've created an object with two fields of the first name and the last name and tried to add the object to list to be displayed below the buttons. However, nothing appears on the screen. The debug message shows that the object is successfully created and added to the list, but there must be something wrong with the way I'm trying to display the values of the object fields. I would be extremely grateful if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Here is the layout xml code (the ListView part):

```html
  <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
```

the Java part:

```
public class Person {
private static String firstname;
private static String lastname;

public Person(String firstname, String lastname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public static String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public static String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public String toString(){
    return  getFirstname()+ " " + getLastname();
}
```

}

and the main function

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private EditText ent_name;
private EditText ent_surname;
private ListView listView;
private Person person;
private String first_name;
private String last_name;
private ArrayAdapter<Person> adapter;
private List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ent_name = findViewById(R.id.txt_firstName);
    ent_surname = findViewById(R.id.txt_lastName);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, people);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


}

public void clear(View view) {
    ent_name.setText("");
    ent_surname.setText("");

}

public void add(View view) {
    first_name = ent_name.getText().toString();
    last_name = ent_surname.getText().toString();

    Person person = new Person(first_name, last_name);
    people = Arrays.asList(person);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

The debug log

```
people.get(0) = {Person@11058} "Harry Potter"
this = {MainActivity@11055} 
view = {AppCompatButton@11057} "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{1bc3388 VFED..C.. ...P.... 720,0-1028,168 #7f070019 app:id/add}"
person = {Person@11058} "Harry Potter"
 firstname = "Harry"
 lastname = "Potter"
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@10711} "class com.example.lavague.list.Person"
 shadow$_monitor_ = 0
adapter = {ArrayAdapter@11059} 
people = {ArrayList@11056}  size = 1
 0 = {Person@11058} "Harry Potter"
```

Comment: Where is add() being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the `add()` method is supposed to take the name and last name from the `edit texts`, create a new `Person` and add it to the list of `people`.

If this is the case, then you should change `people = Arrays.asList(person);` by `people.add(person);` The way it is now it will always replace the existing list with a new list of one person.

Also, I don't see any reason for the `add()` method to receive a `View` as parameter. Unless you are planning to do something else, you could remove that.

At last, in the code you posted, `add()` is not being called in any place. Perhaps it should be called inside an `OnClickListener` in a button on the layout.

**EDIT I**

The way you are using the Person class it shouldn't have static members.
Static members are shared among all the instances. So changing the name, if it is static, will change the name for all the Person instances.

```
public class Person {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    public Person(String firstname, String lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public static String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public static String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return  getFirstname()+ " " + getLastname();
    }
}
```

For the crash please check Logcat at the botton on the left:

[image]

And look for an `Exception` with a `stack trace`.
The stack trace has all the hierachy of calls upto the point where the exception is thrown.
You will need to add that to the question.

Comment: That's correct, the idea is to create an new Person and add to the list people. 
I'm sorry I forgot to include the code for the add method - it's the function bound to the button that adds the entered values on click. I've changed asList to add() and the app crashed.

Comment: Also the way you use Person, the attributes and methods shouldn't be static.

Comment: I hope, I got it right:
people = {ArrayList@11052}  size = 1
this = {MainActivity@11051} 
view = {AppCompatButton@11053} "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{1bc3388 VFED..C.. ...P.... 720,0-1028,168 #7f070019 app:id/add}"
person = {Person@11054} "Harry Potter"
adapter = {ArrayAdapter@11055} 
people = {ArrayList@11052}  size = 1

Comment: Please edit the question and add it there. I can't read it in the comments.

Comment: My bad, sorry. I'm an absolute newbie to both Java and Android studio. I've edited the original question, but not sure I got the right thing.

Comment: See my Edit I in the answer.

Comment: Thank you, Juan. I've gone through my code one more time, edited the Person class and it worked. Thanks again!